# Replacing gas burner in a vented glass 3 sided fireplave

Tags: gas

Our fireplace, installed in mid 80's has a burner that is completly worn out. Is is possible to install a new burner that is not made by original maker? When I've asked at fireplace shops they claim that the entire unit, box and all must be torn out and replaced...really? I want to know if I can purchase a burner and replace, if so is there anything other than where the burner connects to gas line I need to know an
Bout? Thanks

Comment: I think for liability reasons if not a direct replacement the store may say everything needs to be replaced. Is the original MFG still in business? Contacting them you may be able to purchase a new burner or find one with a similar design and BTU rating to replace the worn out one.

Answer (score 1):

You must get a new burner from the manufacturer, anything else could potentially end in disaster.remember to make sure if it's natural or propane gas burner.